# Lucene IndexWriter AlreadySet Exception

Tags: lucene, indexwriter

I am trying to create an IndexWriter and write to a Lucene Index. Here is my code:

```
public class Indexer {

    public static Analyzer _analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48);

    private void WriteToIndex() {
        var config = new IndexWriterConfig(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, _analyzer).SetUseCompoundFile(false);
        using (IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(LuceneDirectory, config)) <-- This throws an error!
        {
            // ....
        }
    }

}
```

But I keep getting an exception when trying to create the IndexWriter:

```
Exception thrown: 'Lucene.Net.Util.SetOnce`1.AlreadySetException' in Lucene.Net.dll

Additional information: The object cannot be set twice!
```

What am I doing wrong? The code compiles perfectly. I'm using Lucene.NET, but I'm guessing it should apply to Java too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are reusing an `IndexWriterConfig`, which is not intended to be shared between `IndexWriter` instances. Generate a new IndexWriterConfig instead, and it should work fine.